# Conditional rendering tickvalues in D3JS in Vue3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vuejs3, histogram, x-axis

unfortunately I'm not able to find my mistake, so i'm asking you in the hope that someone can help me.
What I want to have in the end is, that only every fifth bin is labeled, if the binNumber is higher than 30.
I tried every inline condition I know, but non of this worked so far.

What I currently have is the following:

```
const binWidth = d3.max(testData, (d) => d.expressionValue) / (binNumber - 1);

      const bins = Array.from({ length: binNumber}, () => ({
        x0: 0,
        x1: 0,
        length: 0, // gets updated later on
      }));

      bins.forEach((bin, i) => {
        bin.x0 = (i === 0) ? 0 : bins[i - 1].x1;
        bin.x1 = bin.x0 + binWidth;
      });

      testData.forEach((d) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < binNumber; i++) {
        const bin = bins[i];
        if (d.expressionValue >= bin.x0 && d.expressionValue < bin.x1) {
          bin.length += 1;
          if(this.proteinId != null && d.proteinId == this.proteinId){
            binIndexOfInputProteinId = i; // bin at position i needs to be in a different color
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      });

       const x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(testData, (d) => d.expressionValue) + binWidth])
            .range([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(bins, (d) => d.length)])
          .range([height - marginBottom, marginTop + 15]);

      const svg = d3.select(this.$refs.barContainer)
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height + 20])
          .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");

      const binMidpoints = bins.map((bin) => (bin.x0 + bin.x1) / 2);

      svg.append("g")   
        .selectAll()
        .data(bins)
        .join("rect")
          .attr("x", (d) => x(d.x0) + 1)
          .attr("width", (d) => x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) -1)
          .attr("y", (d) => y(Math.max(d.length, 0.05)))
          .attr("height", (d) => Math.max(y(0) - y(d.length), minRectHeight))
          .attr("fill", (d, i) => (i == binIndexOfInputProteinId && binIndexOfInputProteinId != null) ? "red" : "steelblue"); 

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickValues([
                ...((this.binNumber < 10) ? binMidpoints : []),
                ...((this.binNumber <= 20) ? bins.map((bin, i) => (bin.x1)) : []),
                ...((this.binNumber > 30) ? bins.map((bin, i) => (i % 5 === 0 ? bin.x1 : null)) : [])
              ])
              .tickSizeOuter(0)
              .tickFormat((d) => d.toFixed(1)))
          .call((g) => g.append("text")
              .attr("x", width)
              .attr("y", marginBottom + 15)
              .attr("fill", "currentColor")
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Protein expression value →"))
          .selectAll("text")
          .attr("style", `font-size: 18px`);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
           .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10))
          .call((g) => g.append("text")
              .attr("x", marginLeft - 180)
              .attr("y", marginTop)
              .attr("fill", "currentColor")
              .attr("text-anchor", "start")
              .text("↑ Frequency of proteins with corresponding expression"))
              .selectAll("text")
              .attr("style", `font-size: 18px`);
      
      return svg.node();
```

The important part is the following:

```
.tickValues([
                ...((this.binNumber < 10) ? binMidpoints : []),
                ...((this.binNumber <= 30) ? bins.map((bin, i) => (bin.x1)) : []),
                ...((this.binNumber > 30) ? bins.map((bin, i) => (i % 5 === 0 ? bin.x1 : null)) : [])
              ])
```

The first two conditions work well. The problem is the last one. If I have found this out correctly, then this does not work because of the "null". However, I have also tried "undefined" and an empty string, but unfortunately that doesn't work either. In my histogram there are simply no more axes to be seen.

Then I tried a different inline condition, because I thought maybe I must not do anything in the else statement:

```
...((this.binNumber > 20) && bins.map((bin, i) => (i % 5 === 0 ? bin.x1)))
```

There the error occurs that the ":" is missing.

```
...((this.binNumber > 30) ? bins.map((bin, i) => (i % 5 === 0 ? bin.x1)) : [])
```

Didn"t worked as well.

Can you please help me how I can solve this?
Thank you very much :D